# Jenkins system generates lots of logs and jobs dont exit

Tags: jenkins, system, jobs

One of our jenkins server went for a reboot and after that the jenkins.log files gets lots of logs like below

```
3949    ABORTED
66025   SUCCESS
59697   SUCCESS
263009  SUCCESS
50257   SUCCESS
47574   SUCCESS
9927    SUCCESS
38351   SUCCESS
73544   SUCCESS
110265  SUCCESS
110536  SUCCESS
74935   SUCCESS
38344   SUCCESS
110537  SUCCESS
```

This is going non-stop even after many reboot. I even tried switching off all logs. still no luck.
Tried restoring a backup config from a week back. Still these logs are generating.
The real issue I have is that the jobs complete executing but not exiting. It keeps spinning for several minutes.

[image]

Because of this, executors are not released and jobs are getting queued.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own Question if it can help anyone having this issue.

I found out that one of the plugin that we installed called "Build History Metrics" is the culprit.
We had a huge number of jobs and a lots of build history in each of those jobs.
Looks like 'Build History Metrics' plugin is pooling them all and pushing the mentioned logs jenkins.log file even if I disable all logging.

After removing this plugin, the log messages stopped, jobs exit immediately after it completes execution and resources are freed up.